Showing ln of an integral is convex?
I am reading a paper and one of the proofs involves the integral
$$M_p=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^d}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\|\mathbf{u}\|^p\exp\left(-\frac{\|\mathbf{u}\|^2}{2}\right)\,d\mathbf{u},$$
which is a function of $p$. The author claims that $\phi(p):=\ln(M_p)$ is convex with very little explanation as to why. I tried thinking about it, but finding a second derivative seems extremely messy, and I cannot figure out a way to use the convex combination definition to show this, as exponents cannot be "turned" into addition. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Switching to polar system of coordinates $$M(p)=Const_1\cdot\int_0^\infty x^{p+d-1}e^{-\frac{x^2}2}dx=Const_2\cdot 2^\frac p2\Gamma\big(\frac{p+d}2\big)$$

HINTS:

Use polar coordinates. $\|\mathbf{u}\|^2=r^2$ and $d\mathbf{u}=r^{d-1}drd\Omega_d$. Here $d\Omega_d$ is the surface element in $d$ dimensions. When you integrate this last part you get a constant that depends on $d$.
For the radial part, perform a change of variables: $r^2/2=y$, $rdr=dy$. You will get an integral of the type $$\int_0^\infty y^{q-1}e^{-y}dy=\Gamma(q)$$
Assuming $q>1$, you can use properties of the Gamma function, in particular the derivative, to show that your expression is a convex function

